# How can provide link to a record from visualforce page using outputlink

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Could anyone help me out on providing link in this scenario

```
<apex:repeat var="slot" value="{!liTimeSlots}">

<tr class="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'Free', 'Fill')}">
    <td ><apex:outputText value="{!slot.tstart1}"/></td>

      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), 'Free', slot.sAppointment.name)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), '', slot.sAppointment.Appointment_Type__c)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment), '', slot.sAppointment.Patient__c)}"/></td>
        </tr> 
    <tr >
    <td></td>

      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), ' ', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.name)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), '', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.Appointment_Type__c)}"/></td>
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISNULL(slot.sAppointmentOverlap), '', slot.sAppointmentOverlap.Patient__c)}"/></td>
        </tr>   
 </apex:repeat>
```

I want to show the link only if slot.sAppointment or  slot.sAppointmentOverlap is not null.

Any idea how to approach this.

Thanks

Prady

Comment: No idea why someone voted this down, it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like pretty much all of the `apex:` Visualforce tags, `apex:outputLink` has a `rendered` attribute which can be used to show or hide it, and this can use a merge field / formula for the value, so you'll be looking for something along the lines of:

```
<apex:outputLink value="url" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(slot.sAppointment)) || NOT(ISNULL(slow.AppointmentOverlap))}">The link</a>
```

Another trick I use for conditional rendering for a group of markup elements is to wrap them in an `apex:variable` tag:

```
<apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!ShouldThisRender}">
   <!-- Some page elements -->
</apex:outputVariable>
```